# Error when using cv::Mat.submat opencv

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I am trying to use opencv `submat` function. Basically my code is the following:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

Mat img1 = imread(img1Path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat img2 = imread(img2Path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

Rect ROI = Rect(x ,y, width, height);
addWeighted(img1.submat(ROI), 0.5, img2, 0.5, 0.0, img1.submat(ROI));
```

When I am trying to compile using Android Studio the following compilation error is showing:

```
Error:error: 'class cv::Mat' has no member named 'submat'
```

From my end I am including the necessary headers for `submat` and I searched quite a lot but I don't know why the compiler is giving this compilation error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you probably confused the c++ and the java api:

java:

```
Mat roi = m.submat(rect);
```

c++:

```
Mat roi = m(rect);
```